# Getting Attribute [modelAttribute] invalid for tag [form] according to TLD

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I am completely new to Spring and I am getting error "**Getting Attribute [modelAttribute] invalid for tag [form] according to TLD**" 
while running below code.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%> 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Personal Info Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Personal Info Page</h1></center>
<form:form  method="post" action="/user-web/processuserregistration.do" modelAttribute="user" >
      <table>
          <tr>
              <td>First Name:</td>
              <td><form:input path="firstName"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Last Name:</td>
              <td><form:input path="lasttName"/></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td>Middle Name:</td>
              <td><form:input path="middleName"/></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td colspan="2">
                  <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>

</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

After running the piece of code, I am getting below error :

```
Oct 07, 2019 9:31:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/user-web] threw exception [/jsp/person.jsp (line: [9], column: [0]) Attribute [modelAttribute] invalid for tag [form] according to TLD] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/person.jsp (line: [9], column: [0]) Attribute [modelAttribute] invalid for tag [form] according to TLD
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:292)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:115)
```

Is there anything I can do to resolve the error ?
I am completely new to Spring

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I am going to say upfront, I am not a JSP developer, but I use Java and HTML/CSS/JS all day.  I have not compiled a JSP page, but I know it is just HTML with some script.  What I can help you with, is just giving you a small heads up that the word "attribute" when used with/about HTML refers to the "assignment-looking-like" things that are inside of an HTML element.  For instance, you are using an HTML 'form' element.

According to w3schools.com, which I refer to at least once a day when I'm coding, the HTML form element is allowed the following attributes...  ***The text inside the next "Comment Block" has been word-for-word copied from the following link***: [https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13722/tld.htm#TAGLB120)

> **The Action Attribute** The action attribute defines the action to be performed when the form is submitted.  Normally, the form data is sent
>   to a web page on the server when the user clicks on the submit button.
>   In the example above, the form data is sent to a page on the server
>   called "/action_page.php". This page contains a server-side script
>   that handles the form data:
>
> ```
> <form action="/action_page.php">
> ```
>
> If the action attribute is omitted, the action is set to the current
>   page.
>
> **The Target Attribute** The target attribute specifies if the submitted result will open in a new browser tab, a frame, or in the
>   current window.  The default value is "_self" which means the form
>   will be submitted in the current window.  To make the form result open
>   in a new browser tab, use the value "_blank"... Example:
>
> ```
> <form action="/action_page.php" target="_blank">
> ```
>
> Other legal values are "_parent", "_top", or a name representing the
>   name of an iframe.
>
> **The Method Attribute** The method attribute specifies the HTTP method (GET or POST) to be used when submitting the form data:
>
> `<form action="/action_page.php" method="get"`>
>   **or**
>
> ```
> <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
> ```
>
> [1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13722/tld.htm#TAGLB120): https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Important Point being: ***HTML Form's may not have*** the "modelAttribute='user'" line that you have added...

```
<form:form  method="post" action="/user-web/processuserregistration.do" modelAttribute="user" >
```

According to the Oracle Documentation, a TLD is the Tag Library Descriptor - and it is used in JSP programming.  Here is a link to Oracle's TLD page.  Again, I'm sorry for posting as non-JSP guy... but maybe this will help :)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13722/tld.htm#TAGLB120

Comment: `<form:form modelAttribute="">` it is there, i am using regularly without any issue. It is spring mvc form tag.

Comment: Well, he's using JSP, and that is a Java Server Pages TLD link.  The error he posted uses the TLD acronym, and I have a link to an Oracle Page for how to define "Tag Library Descriptors"  Whatever the case, 'modelAttribute' is not a standard HTML 5 Attribute.   There's an Oracle Document Page about it on the website... In the last link I included in the "answer."

Comment: Nothing wrong with your answer. Just i gave you info.